# MVC null ViewBag in JQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, viewbag

I have a ViewBag that has no value. I am not even defining the ViewBag.SelectVale
in my controller so I would expect it to be a null value.

When I do the following in JQuery but does not work:

```
    if ('@ViewBag.SelectVale' == null){ 

     // do something

     }
```

What works instead is something like:

```
    if ('@ViewBag.SelectVale' == ""){ 

     // do something

     }
```

Comment: But you put the razor eval in quotes... Making it a string in JavaScript (incidentally where you are doing your comparison). If you look at the HTML that gets generated by your razor view it should be obvious...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the .NET framework `null` gets output as an empty string, so if you look at the actual javascript being sent to the browser, in the first case it will say:

```
if ('' == null)
```

... and in the second case it will say:

```
if ('' == "")
```

Most javascript programmers would tell you to just change your statement to:

```
if ('@ViewBag.SelectVale')
```

... because empty strings evaluate to `false` when they are treated as boolean values in javascript.

Or, since there doesn't appear to be anything really dynamic happening here, try this:

```
@if(ViewBag.SelectVale == null) {
    <text>
        // do something in javascript.
    </text>
}
```

... which will avoid even outputting the "do something" javascript since you know when you are rendering the page that SelectVale is null.

Comment: if ('@ViewBag.SelectVale' == '') worked for me. Thank you